# How to delete, skip background of arrow Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have image below.

[image]

I put it in my button control. I got button like this

[image]

I want to get button like on the first image.
Like arrow, not like button with image of arrow.
My application will be touch application.
How I can achive it?

Answer (score 2):

What you see in second image is the default `ControlTemplate` of the button. To make it look like first image, you should customize the `ControlTemplate` of the button. Expression Blend may help you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396